# Wildcard SSL is not showing on subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a website **mydomain.edu**, hosted on amazon server. 
I installed an wildcard ssl certificate for *.mydomain.edu by using shell access through putty by using following method -
I find the old certificate path on /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.edu-ssl.conf and replaced the old certificate, private key and intermediate certificate with the new one. And restarted apache server.
All work well and I got new ssl certificate showing on mydomain.edu.

But the ssl certificate wont show on sub1.mydomain.edu and sub2.mydomain.edu

What changes should I have to make to apply same wildcard certificate?
I have Dabin - ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

I simply created the  markeup's for all the subdomains I needed to word with my wildcard SSL.
For each  markeup's for a subdomain I created the secure markup

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         SSLEngine on
         SSLProtocol all

        ServerName sub1.mydomain.edu
        ServerAlias www.sub1.mydomain.edu
        DocumentRoot /home/path/to/mysubdomain/directory
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub1.mydomain.edu.in_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub1.mydomain.edu.in_access.log combined

         SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
         SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/privatekey.key
         SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediateCASSLca.crt

        <Directory "/home/path/to/mysubdomain/directory">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I added the following line for unsecured to secure redirection:-

**Redirect permanent / https://sub1.mydomain.edu**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName sub1.mydomain.edu
        ServerAlias www.sub1.mydomain.edu
        **Redirect permanent / https://www.sub1.mydomain.edu**

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/path/to/mysubdomain/directory

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub1.mydomain.edu_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub1.mydomain.edu_access.log combined

        <Directory "/home/path/to/mysubdomain/directory">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```